# Recycler View doesn't show anything

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

### list_users.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/user_list_bg"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_image_view"
        android:layout_width="90sp"
        android:layout_height="90sp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_image_placeholder"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        app:border_width="1sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

    </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hardik Dhuri"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_message_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Bro"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

### fragment_chats.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.fragments.ChatsFragment"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_users_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_users"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

### ListUsersAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.samvach.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.samvach.R
import com.example.samvach.models.User

class ListUsersAdapter(private val userList: ArrayList<User>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListUsersAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_users, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = userList[position]
        holder.name.text = item.name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_tv)
    }
}
```

### ChatsFragment.kt

Here I am getting data from firebase. I checked the data by logging it and it seems fine only thing i can't figure out is where is the actual error in my recycler view. I create few users manually to test and they don't show up either.

```
package com.example.samvach.main.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.samvach.R
import com.example.samvach.adapters.ListUsersAdapter
import com.example.samvach.databinding.FragmentChatsBinding
import com.example.samvach.models.User
import com.google.firebase.database.*


class ChatsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentChatsBinding
    private lateinit var dbref: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var usersArrayList: ArrayList<User>

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ChatsFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: ChatsViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false)
    }


    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ChatsViewModel::class.java]
        binding = FragmentChatsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.listUsersRv.setHasFixedSize(true)
        usersArrayList = arrayListOf(
            User(
                name = "Banana"
            ),
            User(
                name = "Apple"
            ),
            User(
                name = "Kiwi"
            ),
            User(
                name = "Orange"
            )
        )
        binding.listUsersRv.adapter = ListUsersAdapter(usersArrayList)
//        getUserData()
    }

    private fun getUserData() {
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")

        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                usersArrayList.clear()
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val user = userSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                        Log.i("USER", "${user!!.name}")
                        usersArrayList.add(user)
                    }
                    binding.listUsersRv.adapter = ListUsersAdapter(usersArrayList)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })

    }

}
```

### User.kt

```
package com.example.samvach.models

data class User (
    var email: String?= null,
    var name: String?= null,
    var profilePicture: String?= null,
    var uid: String?= null,

)
```

Comment: Why you are using `onActivityCreated` which is already deprecated?

Comment: Was trying different ways to solve the error. Hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in `binding = FragmentChatsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`, try to init your binding in `onCreateView` like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false)
    binding = FragmentChatsBinding.bind(view)
    return binding.root
}
```

or move your code of onActivityCreated to onViewCreated and use view instance

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentChatsBinding.bind(view)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ChatsViewModel::class.java]
    binding.listUsersRv.setHasFixedSize(true)
    usersArrayList = arrayListOf(
        User(
            name = "Banana"
        ),
        User(
            name = "Apple"
        ),
        User(
            name = "Kiwi"
        ),
        User(
            name = "Orange"
        )
    )
    binding.listUsersRv.adapter = ListUsersAdapter(usersArrayList)
//        getUserData()
}
```

Comment: The problem was in binding initialisation. I applied the code and now it works. Thank you Pablo for your help. :)